# How to pass command-line parameters to a Perl script executed from Python

Tags: python

I have written this code to run a Perl script from my Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

var = "/some/file/path/"
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./SignalPktSender.pl ", var], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But my perl script needs command line arguments. How can I pass command arguments to the Perl script when it is run from my Python script?

Comment: Exactly the way you do it right now...

Answer (score 1):

From [the Python docs on the subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constuctor):

> `class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)`
>
> Arguments are:
>
> args should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. The program to execute is normally the first item in the args sequence or the string if a string is given, but can be explicitly set by using the executable argument.

Your code so far is:

`pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./SignalPktSender.pl ", var], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`

which has a list at the start of the arguments you're sending, and it looks like you're already passing a command line argument (`var`) - just add your other command line arguments to the list after `var`.